Python x in y in z
A code reviewer flagged to me that I had written the code:
assert b'some html' in response.data in response.data

This is clearly incorrect but I missed this since it passed the test as expected.
Doing more testing in a Python 3.12 REPL, it seems the syntax x in y in z === x in y && y in z. However I couldn't find any information on what this syntax is or what other operators have similar functionality. This seems to be something special and not operator precedence as both (x in y) in z and x in (y in z) lead to exceptions.
Does this kind of syntax have a name?

This is the membership test operator.

Comparison chaining - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

FWIW: (x in y) in z is checking to see if the Boolean result of x in y is in the iterable z. This can work so long as z is an iterable. On the other hand, x in (y in z) will always fail with TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable because the result of y in z is a Boolean, not an iterable, ergo it can't be tested for membership (i.e., x in True doesn't work)

@JRiggles Not necessarily. Depending on the types of y and z, y in z might return something other than a Boolean value, and that object may itself support inclusion testing. (Types that do that are doing some higher-order abstraction, so it's not something you'll see often, but it's not impossible.)

@chepner good to know! Can you think of an example? I've only ever seen it return a Boolean, but I've never done anything particularly spicy with membership tests...

Some SQL libraries could do this kind of thing. For example consider something like select(User.name).where(User.name in Array(["John", "Jane"])). The Python code isn't literally checking if a column object User.name is in some array of names, but rather constructing an object that maps to a WHERE clause, so that the entire expression represents a query like SELECT name from User where name in ("John", "Jane").

@chepner That's definitely an interesting edge case...thanks for the heads up

The syntax you're referring to is called "chained comparison" or "chained operators." It's a feature of Python that allows you to chain multiple comparison operators together in a single expression.
In Python, the expression x in y in z is equivalent to (x in y) and (y in z). This means that x is checked to be in y, and then y is checked to be in z, and the overall expression evaluates to True only if both conditions are True.
This syntax can make code more concise and readable in certain situations, but it's essential to be cautious when using it to ensure clarity and avoid confusion, as you've experienced in your code review.
For More Clarification, have a look at this article:  https://wiingy.com/learn/python/chaining-comparison-operators-in-python/
